# Does here traffic api contains any information about pedestrian traffic flows?

Tags: here-api

`Here` sales manager says that their api has information about pedestrian traffic flow.

However I can't find any documentation on the pedestrian traffic flows. All i've got is pedestrian `RoutingModeType` for `route api`, not for `traffic flow api`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, our HERE traffic/other HERE APIs do not contain any information about pedestrian traffic flow as our traffic flow is coming from normal car probes. We suggest you to check the below documents could help.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic-api/dev_guide/index.html